# Is it possible to use facebook server side authentification and facebook ios sdk

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, server-side

Facebook has a Server-Side Authentification - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/. This method consists of three main steps:

1) Client side login. As a result we get a code (&code=CODE_GENERATED_BY_FACEBOOK)

2) We pass this code to server.

3) Server obtains access token using this request -

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&code=CODE_GENERATED_BY_FACEBOOK
```

I haven't found how to use this method on ios to get code on client side. Is it posisble with facebook ios sdk? As i see right now FBSession returns only client side access token, which is short-lived.

Or are there any other ways to obtain long-lived access token on server side?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Comment: I saw this link. So how should i use facebook-ios-sdk to get secure long-lived token on the server side? There is nothing about it in your answer.

Comment: If you have a short-lived access token, you can extend it with the method described there.

Comment: I can get client side token, which I can extend only for a short period. If I could get short lived token on server side, it will solve the problem.

Comment: i was wrong, the deal was in offline_access deprecation setting of facebook app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i get it

I needed to enable option about offline_access deprecation. It is named "Remove offline_access permission" in Advanced app settings.

Than any short-lived token passed to server side and extented will result in long-lived token.